# How to union two shapefiles in R

Tags: shapefile, r

I try to union two shapefiles in R. I read them by st_read function in sf package.Here is the summary of these two files.
[image]

1. I tried to use rbind, it works, but I don't want the black line between the two areas in the right corner.
   [image]
2. I tried the union function, got a new file with two rows, but cannot plot it,

> Error: stat_sf requires the following missing aesthetics: geometry

[image]

Comment: The only thing you can do with shapefiles in R is read them in. You can't union them. You would seem to want to know how to union spatial objects, but you've not told us how you've read them in from shapefiles. Did you use `st_read` from the `sf` package? You should add this information to your question and show us what the objects are like via the `summary` or `print` functions.

Comment: Thank you for informing me

Comment: You can also improve you questions by pasting text instead of images when possible, making simple examples that illustrate your problem using data we can all have (examples from the R help are a good source for this), and showing all the working needed - and no more than is necessary - to duplicate your problem.

Answer (score 1):

First I've created two objects that are analagous to yours - these are MULTIPOLYGON geometries but that shouldn't make any difference:

```
> summary(n1)
     FIPS                    geometry
 Length:1           MULTIPOLYGON :1  
 Class :character   epsg:4267    :0  
 Mode  :character   +proj=long...:0  
> summary(n2)
     FIPS                    geometry
 Length:1           MULTIPOLYGON :1  
 Class :character   epsg:4267    :0  
 Mode  :character   +proj=long...:0
```

Each of these is a spatial data frame with one row. Using `rbind` creates a data frame with two rows, so you see two objects:

```
plot(st_geometry(rbind(n1,n2)))
```

[image]

To merge them into single o, use `st_union`:

```
n12 = st_union(n1,n2)
plot(st_geometry(n12))
```

[image]

Notice you now have a single row and the attributes from both:

```
> n12
Simple feature collection with 1 feature and 2 fields
Geometry type: POLYGON
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: -81.74107 ymin: 36.23436 xmax: -80.90344 ymax: 36.58965
Geodetic CRS:  NAD27
   FIPS FIPS.1                       geometry
1 37009  37005 POLYGON ((-81.17667 36.4154...
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It is solved!